# How do you activate line-wrapping in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, scroll

How do you use line-wrap in emacs?
So that the portion that doesn't fit on the screen isn't shown as opposed to shown on the next line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you describe sounds more like linewrap than scrolling.  If that's what you're actually interested in, it's controlled with buffer-local variable `truncate-lines`.  You can use customization to set it globally, or use hooks.  For example, I used to prevent linewrap in dired with this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))
```

Comment: tx man, for the term :  

M-xtoggle-truncate-lines did the trick.  Although for me (emacs newbie) there's only a fine line between scrolling and truncating, since scrolling seems to imply truncation.

Comment: This worked for me. I put it in init.el for markdown, ie `(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook (lambda () (setq truncate-lines t)))`

Answer (score 9):

toggle-truncate-lines allows you to turn it on-off (as Peter noted in a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950340/how-do-you-activate-line-wrapping-in-emacs/950406#950406))

I have it mapped to a function-key:

```
(define-key global-map [f5] 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

It won't work in vertically-split (partial-width) windows unless truncate-partial-width-windows is set to nil (from my .emacs):

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows nil) ;; for vertically-split windows
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also change this from the menu.

Options->Line Wrapping in this Buffer->Truncate Long Lines

Or if you want this globally you can use the function

global-visual-line-mode

Comment: I don't have that `global-visual-line-mode` function.  I'm on GNU 22.3.1, is it newer that that?

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 23.0.91.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) on XP.

Comment: Yes, that feature is since version 23.

Answer (score 3):

i prefer these settings:

```
;; disable line wrap
(setq default-truncate-lines t)
;; make side by side buffers function the same as the main window
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows nil)
;; Add F12 to toggle line wrap
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

Comment: For me, `(setq default-truncate-lines t)` did not work, but `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` did. Emacs 27.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
;; Wrapping the lines
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x p") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

This works with Emacs-27.1